# How can I troubleshoot the installation of this Nuget package?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget

I am trying to install the EnterpriseLibrary for Transient Fault Handling. This is a Microsoft package. When i try to install it I am getting the following error :

```
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 char
acters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.TransientFaultHandling
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], PathTooLongException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

I have tried selecting the package from the Nuget ui. I have tried manually installing the package using the Nuget command line.

I have tried manually installing the dependencies one by one. It fails on the same package every time.

My project location is the default MyDocuments/visualstudio/projects location.

Any ideas ?

Comment: There is an opened issue in NuGet project: https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/4311.

Comment: update to open issue - NuGet is over to GitHub - https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3324

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It looks like your project path is long enough that when the package is installed, adding the package folder fails because it reached the qualified name length limit.

I mean : 
[drive]:\Users[user]\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects[yourproject]\packages\ +
\EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.TransientFaultHandling\
has more than the limit.

Can you move you project somewhere else ?

Comment: Its in the default location for visual studio projects. I will probably create a projects folder at the root of my drive. This is an odd error to see with a default project location, specifically because nothing about this path is exceptional or unusually long. I've always thought the path char limit needs to be increased in the OS but, that is a different subject.

Comment: Thanks I moved my project to root drive, and it worked.

Comment: when i saw this error i thought this is the issue in nuget package manager..Thanks i have moved my solution in to some other sub-folder and it worked ..

Answer (score 11):

In addition to Alexandre's answer:

You can use the [`subst` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/subst) to keep your path shorter. For example I had a similar problem and used

> subst P: "C:\Users\[username]\Documents\Visual Studio [year]\Projects"

to create a new P: drive (p for projects) and shorten the length of the path by many characters. Make sure that you open the solution by navigating to the solution under P: not C:\Users\Docs..., and you might want to delete any shortcuts (particularly recently opened projects) to the solutions under C:.

You can also create a batch file that contains this and put it in Start Menu/Startup (or C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup) which will run it every time that you start your computer and mean that you always have a P: drive.

Comment: This worked - furthermore I found that after opening the solution from the shortened path, and updating my NuGet packages, I was able to re-open and build my solution from the original, long-path location.

Answer (score 2):

I have also got the same error but it got easily resolved , when i moved my package to one upper level 
drive , or u can probably keep your project inside one folder in

it will surely work rather than giving a lengthy path

drive:\[folder1]\Documents\Visual Studio 2010[folder2][projectname]\ .. \

which exceeds the limit of 248 characters

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the similar issue, however, what I did was to manually download the  file (.nupkg file extension) and then clicking on settings in the Manage NuGet Packages

[image]

Then select your downloaded package (Keep it in a separate folder, you may keep all your downloaded package files in this folder) and update

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes previously my project was in Desktop,I just moved it to one of my Drive,re-started the project,its start worked for me.